# How to find the number of continued fraction from a periodic representation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

**Problem**
Find the number that represented by $[2,2,2 \ldots]$

I know it wasn't difficult, but I was absent the last two classes. So I just want to make sure that I got it right.

My attempt was,
Consider $x = [2;\overline{2}] \implies [2;x]$
        Hence, $x = 2 + \dfrac{1}{x} \Leftrightarrow x = \dfrac{2x + 1}{x} \Leftrightarrow x^2 - 2x - 1 = 0$.
        Solving the quadratic equation we have $x = \sqrt{2} + 1$ since $x > 0$. Therefore
        $[2,2,2, \ldots] = \sqrt{2} + 1$

Is it correct?

Thank you,

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Yes that looks right, and is in fact a different proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Yes - now try something a little harder, like $[2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,\dots]$, with the $3,4$ repeating.

Comment: If you put a number into Wolfram Alpha it'll give you back its continued fraction representation. This isn't the direction you're trying to go, but it'll help  you check your work.

Answer (score 4):

To get this off the Unanswered list:

Yes, your solution is entirely correct. You might like to try to modify your technique to evaluate something that is only eventually periodic, like $[2,\overline{3,4}]$.